# Reading Different Input Types C++

Tags: c++, cin

I am attempting to create a student object which takes the name, id, email, and three grades which are integers.

My code is quite simple and is as follows:

```
studentObj* newStudent = new studentObj;

cout << "Student First Name: ";
getline(cin, newStudent->name);
cout << "Student ID: ";
getline(cin, newStudent->id);
cout << "Student Email: ";
getline(cin, newStudent->email);
cout << "Grade 1: ";
cin >> newStudent->gradeOne;
cout << "Grade 2: ";
cin >> newStudent->gradeTwo;
cout << "Term Grade: ";
cin >> newStudent->termGrade;

cout << "Student Name: " + newStudent->name << endl;
cout << "Student ID: " + newStudent->id << endl;
cout << "Student Email: " + newStudent->email << endl;
cout << "Grade 1: " + newStudent->gradeOne << endl;
cout << "Grade 2: " + newStudent->gradeTwo << endl;
```

I assumed this would run flawlessly, but unfortunately that is not the case. It seems to be an issue mixing the `getline()` and `cin`.

The output is:

```
Student Name: Test Tester
Student ID: abcdef
Student Email: email@test.com
rade 1:
ade 2:
m Grade:
```

I've tried adding `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');` in a few places, but no luck. Any suggestions?
`

Comment: what types do these members of `studentObj` have?

Comment: Psychic debugging session. Your input was: *Grade 1: `1`*, *Grade 2: `2`*, *Term Grade: `3`*.

Comment: Why do you *need* to allocate the `newStudent` from dynamic memory?  C++ is not Java or C#.  Try something like `studentObj newStudent;`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Because I have a vector, `vector <studentObj*> students`, and when I do `students.push_back(newStudent)` it throws an error, so this is how I was able to get around it.

Comment: Try `std::vector<studentObj>` **without** the '*'.  The vector will push a copy of what you give it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add string literals to the integers (well, you can, but in your case you will not get anything meaningful - you will make an offset - so the string output will be `rade 1:` because `"Grade 1" + 1` will point to the string literal `rade 1`).

```
cout << "Student Name: " << newStudent->name << endl;
cout << "Student ID: " << newStudent->id << endl;
cout << "Student Email: " << newStudent->email << endl;
cout << "Grade 1: " << newStudent->gradeOne << endl;
cout << "Grade 2: " << newStudent->gradeTwo << endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `studentObj::gradeOne` and `studentObj::gradeTwo` members are integer values. The string literal `Grade 1:` has type `char*`. An expression of type `pointer + integer` is the same as `pointer[integer]`. When you try to print the grade you are really producing a pointer into the string literal (if you are lucky).